# When to mark function as async

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

Basically, function must be prefixed with `async` keyword if `await` used inside it. But if some function just returns Promise and doesn't awaiting for anything, should I mark the function as `async`?

Seems like both correct or not?

```
// with async (returns Promise)
async getActiveQueue() {
   return redisClient.zrangeAsync(activeQueue, 0, -1);
}

// difference? Both could be awaited isn't it?
getActiveQueue() {
   return redisClient.zrangeAsync(activeQueue, 0, -1);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> if some function just returns Promise and doesn't awaiting for anything, should I mark the function as async?

I would say you shouldn't. The purpose of `async`/`await` is to create (and resolve) the promise for you; if you already have a promise to return, then `async`/`await` won't give you any benefit for that function.

> Both could be awaited isn't it?

`await` works on promises, not functions. So, `await` works fine on any promise, regardless of whether that promise is manually created or created behind the scenes by `async`.

Comment: Using async changes the behaviour of the function for exception handling

Comment: @Eloims: Indeed! If there is a possibility of a synchronous exception being thrown, I would recommend using async, which would capture the exception and resolve the promise with it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be better for clarity, to mark any function that executes asynchronous operation as async?

Comment: @Qwerty: In my code, I prefer a naming convention - an `Async` suffix.

Answer (score 14):

The [`async` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) is not only about allowing the [`await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) in the function. It ensures that your function will **always** return a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), even when exceptions are thrown.

Let's define two identical functions which do not use the `await` keyword:

```
async function fnUsingAsync() {
    // Synchronously throw half of the time
    if (Math.random() < .5)
        throw new Error('synchronous error')

    // Return fulfilled/rejected promises half of the time
    return Math.random() < .5 ?
        Promise.resolve('success') :
        Promise.reject(new Error('asynchronous error');
}

function fnNotUsingAsync(x) {
    // Use the exact same body here than function above
}
```

When calling them, the result is different in case of failure.

```
// when using the async keyword, the function always returns a promise
// which can be fulfilled or rejected.
// No need for try-catch!
fnUsingAsync()
    .then(result => /* result === 'success' */)
    .catch(error => /* catch both synchronous and asynchronous error */);

// Otherwise, you will need to use a try-catch statement, because
// the exception won't be converted to a rejected promise.
try {
    fnNotUsingAsync()
      .then(result => /* result === 'success' */)
      .catch(error => /* catch asynchronous error only */)
}
catch (error) {
    /* catch synchronous error only */
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If the function that you call for some unknown reason throws an error, `async` keyword will make sure that this will be returned as a rejected promise by your function.

`async` keyword might also be used in functions that would wish to return a promise (e.g. for api consistency) just from the return value, without the need to manually create a Promise object.

Due to the above, I would say that `async` keyword is **not always paired with await**.

Answer (score 0):

If your function "doesn't awaiting for anything" - this is usual function, even inside your return function may be async ( this is incapsulation)...